# Is there a reason to use generic traits over specific types in Substrate?

Tags: rust, blockchain, substrate

Is there any reason for me to use the `Hash` abstraction of `sr-primitives` instead of using the `substrate_primitives::hash` and `substrate_primitives::hashing` modules?

It's just that it seems much easier to include `H256` in my code (and use the corresponding hashing functions) than to use the `Hash` trait.

Comment: You tagged your question with `substrate`, would you be interested in a dedicated Stack Exchange Q&A site for Substrate, Polkadot, et al. -- check out the [Area51 Substrate Proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122626/substrate?referrer=NTUwMTkxYjJjOTJiNjE0YzMxYjgwMGNkZmFlYzdhZTczYjk1ZWY3ZGI4NzJmODUwN2RlYTQ2MTNjZTdkOTZhMAzuL-zybtPN9CHzwE-WUdvBC8WxvPG46b4ayadke6kG0)

Answer (score 1):

Substrate is built to be generic and highly customizable. When you write your modules and runtime logic around the `Hash` trait, you gain the benefits of your module being generic over the specific type of `Hash` being used in the runtime.

In this case, you do not need to depend on a specific type in your runtime like `H256`. Instead, you have the ability to write runtime logic which only depends on the properties of a Trait. That means, if at some later point, you wanted to implement a different hash function which results in a different `Hash` type, you would not have to rewrite any code.

Additionally, if you plan on sharing the modules you develop with others, you will want to keep your module as generic as possible as to not force the end blockchain developer to conform to your standards.

These abstractions do add some complexity, and is not strictly needed to make things work. However, it is best practice, and something you might find pays dividends in the long term.